# compose NavHost Start the white Screen

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

My app starts with navigation globally, but I found that when I set the following code, the app will remain blank after startup unless I manually touch the screen.

```
rememberSystemUiController().setStatusBarColor(
 Color.Transparent,
 darkIcons = true //This sentence must be set
)
```

```
fun AppNavigation(
    appNavController:NavHostController = LocalAppNavController.current
) {
    NavHost(
        navController = appNavController,
        startDestination = Screen.Splash.route
    ) {
        composable(route = Screen.Splash.route) {
            SplashScreen()
        }
        composable(route = Screen.HelloScreen.route) {
            HelloScreen()
        }
        composable(route = Screen.HomeScreen.route) {
            val popItem = remember{
                mutableStateOf(NULL_MEDIA_ITEM)
            }
            CompositionLocalProvider(
                LocalHomeNavController provides rememberNavController(),
                LocalNetViewModel provides hiltViewModel(),
                LocalUserViewModel provides hiltViewModel(),
                LocalHomeViewModel provides hiltViewModel(),
                LocalPopWindowItem provides popItem
            ){
                LocalUserViewModel.current.initializeController()
                HomeScreen()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Also provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i have same problem

Comment: after start destination screen call __navHostController.backQueue.size__ getting count as 2 strange!

Answer (score 7):

It seems like a known issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227926002

As of comments - different Xiaomi models affected.
My POCO one affected too.

Answer (score 6):

Put your AppNavigation fun in Scaffold:

```
YourAppTheme {
    Scaffold {
        AppNavigation()
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixed my problem with Xiaomi Mi 11 Lite 5G.

Answer (score 6):

a hack way to fix this:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
      delay(50)
      window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)
}
```

add this to onCreate

Comment: At least, this one works! Ty

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. If the light app theme was settled and I rotated smartphone to different orientation, and then rotated it back, I was shown just a white screen. But once touched, the screen was displayed.

I guess this is a problem only for Xiaomi devices on MIUI: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227926002

Adding `ScaffoldDefaults.contentWindowInsets` before NavHost worked for me:

```
MyAppTheme {
    ScaffoldDefaults.contentWindowInsets // Fixes blank screen for Xiaomi devices
    NavHost(...){
        ...
    }
}
```

POCO X3 NFC, Android 12, MIUI Global 14.0.2

Answer (score 0):

```
YourAppTheme {
Scaffold {
    AppNavigation()
    }
}
```

I verified this method. It doesn't work. Sorry, I can't comment on the above answer

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
  delay(50)
  window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)
}
```

This method does work，Note that the delay time needs to be greater than 40 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Add this to onCreate :

```
fun handleNavigationBugOnXiaomiDevices() {
    window.decorView.post {
        window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)
     }
}
```