# White screen when open app second time using jetpack compose only in Xiaomi models

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation, android-splashscreen

Getting a white screen when I open or rotate the app.
This white screen never goes away until I click/swipe on the white screen and after swipe data is displayed.
This only happens in MI model phones, I have also tried the same code in Samsung phones everything is working there.

**MainActivity code**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            MyNavGraph()
        }
    }
}
```

**NavHost for routing between composable**

```
@Composable
fun MyNavGraph(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController(),
    startDestination: String = HOME_ROUTE,
    route: String = ROOT_ROUTE
) {
    NavHost(
        modifier = modifier,
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = startDestination,
        route = route
    ) {
       homeNavGraph(navController = navController)
    }
}
```

**Nav graph contain composable screen**

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.homeNavGraph(
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    navigation(
        startDestination = Screen.HomeScreen.route,
        route = HOME_ROUTE
    ) {
        composable(
            Screen.HomeScreen.route
        ) {
            val homeBackStackEntry = remember { navController.getBackStackEntry(HOME_ROUTE) }
            // Get the same instance every time
            val homeViewModel: HomeViewModel = hiltViewModel(homeBackStackEntry)

            HomeScreen(
                navController = navController,
                viewModel = homeViewModel
            )
        }
        composable(
            Screen.RingtonesScreen.route
        ) {
            val homeBackStackEntry = remember { navController.getBackStackEntry(HOME_ROUTE) }
            // Get the same instance every time
            val ringtoneViewModel: RingtoneViewModel = hiltViewModel(homeBackStackEntry)

            RingtoneScreen(
                navController = navController,
                ringtoneViewModel
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/72119807/9687246

Comment: Also found that there is an issue with the Xiaomi model. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71939109/9687246

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. If the light app theme was settled and I rotated smartphone to different orientation, and then rotated it back, I was shown just a white screen. But once touched, the screen was displayed.

I guess this is a problem only for Xiaomi devices on MIUI:

[compose NavHost Start the white Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71363125/compose-navhost-start-the-white-screen/71939109)

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227926002

Adding `ScaffoldDefaults.contentWindowInsets` before NavHost worked for me:

```
MyAppTheme {
    ScaffoldDefaults.contentWindowInsets // Fixes blank screen for Xiaomi devices
    NavHost(...){
        ...
    }
}
```

POCO X3 NFC, Android 12, MIUI Global 14.0.2