# Compose app doesn't load api data after launch

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm creating a Pokémon app with Jetpack Compose. I'm testing it with two smartphones: Xioami Mi 11T Pro (Android  12) and Xiaomi Mi 8 Lite (Android 10).

Well, when I launch the app in the Mi 8 Lite, it starts correctly, the pokemon list loads perfectly.
But when I launch the app with the Mi 11 T Pro, it doesn't load, nothing shows. I discovered two things:

1. If I open the Layout Inspector it loads inmediately, without doing anything more...
2. When the screen is empty (just after launch, before it loads), If I click 1-2 times on the screen it starts to send the request and loads correctly.

Why is this happening?

I attach my ViewModel and my MainActivity.

> PokemonListViewModel.kt

```
@HiltViewModel
class PokemonListViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: PokemonRepositoryImpl
) : ViewModel() {

    private var currentPage = 0

    var pokemonList = mutableStateOf<List<PokedexListEntry>>(listOf())
    var loadError = mutableStateOf("")
    var isLoading = mutableStateOf(false)
    var endReached = mutableStateOf(false)

    private var cachedPokemonList = listOf<PokedexListEntry>()
    private var isSearchStarting = true
    var isSearching = mutableStateOf(false)

    init {
        loadPokemonList()
    }

    // TODO: Search online, not only already loaded pokémon
    fun searchPokemonList(query: String) {
        val listToSearch = if (isSearchStarting) {
            pokemonList.value
        } else {
            // If we typed at least one character
            cachedPokemonList
        }
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
            if (query.isEmpty()) {
                pokemonList.value = cachedPokemonList
                isSearching.value = false
                isSearchStarting = true
                return@launch
            }

            val results = listToSearch.filter {
                // Search by name or pokédex number
                it.pokemonName.contains(query.trim(), true) ||
                        it.number.toString() == query.trim()
            }

            if (isSearchStarting) {
                cachedPokemonList = pokemonList.value
                isSearchStarting = false
            }

            // Update entries with the results
            pokemonList.value = results
            isSearching.value = true
        }
    }

    fun loadPokemonList() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            isLoading.value = true

            val result = repository.getPokemonList(PAGE_SIZE, currentPage * PAGE_SIZE)
            when (result) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    endReached.value = currentPage * PAGE_SIZE >= result.data!!.count

                    val pokedexEntries = result.data.results.mapIndexed { index, entry ->
                        val number = getPokedexNumber(entry)
                        val url = getImageUrl(number)
                        PokedexListEntry(
                            entry.name.replaceFirstChar(Char::titlecase),
                            url,
                            number.toInt()
                        )
                    }

                    currentPage++

                    loadError.value = ""
                    isLoading.value = false
                    pokemonList.value += pokedexEntries
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    loadError.value = result.message!!
                    isLoading.value = false
                }
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    isLoading.value = true
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private fun getImageUrl(number: String): String {
        return "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${number}.png"
    }

    private fun getPokedexNumber(entry: Result): String {
        return if (entry.url.endsWith("/")) {
            entry.url.dropLast(1).takeLastWhile { it.isDigit() }
        } else {
            entry.url.takeLastWhile { it.isDigit() }
        }
    }

}
```

> MainActivity.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val argPokemonName = "pokemonName"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            JetpackComposePokedexTheme {
                val navController = rememberNavController()
                NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "pokemon_list_screen") {
                    composable("pokemon_list_screen") {
                        PokemonListScreen(navController = navController)
                    }
                    composable(
                        "pokemon_detail_screen/{$argPokemonName}",
                        arguments = listOf(
                            navArgument(argPokemonName) {
                                type = NavType.StringType
                            }
                        )
                    ) {
                        val pokemonName = remember {
                            it.arguments?.getString(argPokemonName)
                        }
                        PokemonDetailScreen(
                            pokemonName = pokemonName?.lowercase(Locale.ROOT) ?: "",
                            navController = navController
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

If someone knows why it doesn't load... I suspect that maybe init { } or Hilt injection are doing something that makes init doesn't start or something.

Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it seems is a Xiaomi reported Bug that google won't fix, you can see it here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/227926002

It worked for me adding a little delay before set content and it seems to be working:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
            delay(300)
            setContent {
                JetpackComposePokedexTheme {
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
```

Also you can see: [compose NavHost Start the white Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71363125/compose-navhost-start-the-white-screen/72119807#72119807)